# sqlalchemy rank over with order by mysql python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am attempting to run the following query to:

```
SELECT order, user, email, date
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY order ORDER BY date DESC) as ranked
FROM orders
```

Python Code:

```
engine.execute(table('orders'), func.rank().over(partition_by='order', order_by='date').desc().label('ranked'))
```

Error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ObjectNotExecutableError: Not an executable object: <sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.TableClause at 0x2c528354340; tracking>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from sqlalchemy import select, func
from sqlalchemy.sql import table, literal_column, column


query = select(
    [
        column('order'),
        # ...other columns. or you can select all: column('*')
        literal_column(
            str(func.rank().over(partition_by='order', order_by='date DESC'))
        ).label('ranked'),
        # or:
        # literal_column('RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY order ORDER BY date DESC)').label('ranked')
    ]
).select_from(table('orders'))

print(query)
```